# Is possible to use ThemeableBrowser plugin with Ionic2 Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am trying to use ThemeableBrowser plugin in my Ionic2 project using Typescript.
I have tried by many ways, but no success.

a) adding plugin in my project (following documentation from plugin in git)
I got the error 'cordova is not defined'

b) I tried with typings
"typings install dt~cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser --save --global"
I got the error: 'typings ERR! message Unable to find "cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser" ("dt") in the registry.'

c) I tried to use 3rd javascript library in typescript project.
 
- I put the 'themeablebrowser.js' in www directory of my project.
- I added this file in index.html.
- I declared the 'ThemeableBrowser' var in my 'page.ts' 
- When I called ThemeableBrowser.open('url', '_blank', options)
I got the error 'open is not a function'

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: I solved using option (a), adding `declare var cordova: any;` Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

the cordova plugin is now available as ionic 2 plugin [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser/)